# JSON: Add pointer

Tags: javascript

I have an automatially made json that looks like:

```
{
    "node_id_1": {
        "x": -87,
        "y": 149
    },
    "node_id_2": {
        "x": -24,
        "y": 50
    },
    "node_id_3": {
        "x": 55,
        "y": -32
    }
}
```

I have problems to access the a specific node_id to get its x and y values. My idea is to automatically add an `"id:"` before e.g. `"node_id_1"` and then to flatten the array.
Could you give me a hint how to add this `"id:"`? Or is there another elegant way to access the IDs?
Thank you a lot!
Best regards

Comment: To access IDs you can use `Object.keys(json)`

Comment: "I have problems to access the a specific node_id" What problems do you have? What ways did you try? What is the expected result? How is your result different.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if you mean what I think you do, a simple `Object.keys(...).map` should cut it, or even a little `for..in`

Comment: So basically you need all the objects indexed, so you would like to have an array instead of the object? Or will the node_ids have numbers which are not in order? In both cases it's very easy to achieve what you want.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't need to add an extra ID property when it already has a key that is the same. What exactly are you trying to do

Comment: If you know what ids you want to look up and are just having trouble accessing them, you could use the id string to look up your x/y values: https://jsfiddle.net/e04Lrbzd/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A possibility using [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), if this is actually what you are attempting to do? Perhaps you could clarify your question with some further description and examples of code you were using with which you were trying to access the data?

```js
function clamp(value, min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
}
const jsonString = '{"node_id_1":{"x":-87,"y":149},"node_id_2":{"x":-24,"y":50},"node_id_3":{"x":55,"y":-32}}';
const javascriptObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
const mySortedArray = [];
// Depending on your preference you could use Array#map here
// instead or even create an iterator for your object.
for (let key of Object.keys(javascriptObject)) {
  mySortedArray.push({
    id: key,
    value: Object.assign({}, javascriptObject[key])
  });
}
mySortedArray.sort((a, b) => {
  // Probably overkill, but precise.
  return clamp(Math.trunc(a.id.localeCompare(b.id)), -1, 1);
});
document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(mySortedArray, null, 2);
console.log(mySortedArray);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

References:

- [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)
- [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [String#localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)
- [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the function I was looking for!

Comment: Would the down-voter care to comment as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Transform the JSON to an array if the IDs are in order and start from 0. (see output1)

If that's not the case you can just string-split the text away and make a new object only having the ids as properties. (see output2)

Or, if you want to be really fancy, you can create an array which contains all of the nodes with their respective id added. (see output3)

```
var list = {
    "node_id_1": {
        "x": -87,
        "y": 149
    },
    "node_id_2": {
        "x": -24,
        "y": 50
    },
    "node_id_3": {
        "x": 55,
        "y": -32
    }
};
var output1 = [];
var output2 = {};
var output3 = [];
for(var node in list){
    if(list.hasOwnProperty(node)){
        // variant 1
        output1.push(list[node]);
        // variant 2
        // node.split('_') will result in an array containing ['node','id','someNumber']
        // since you only want the number, we take the 3rd element node.split('_')[2],
        // and use that as property name for our new object
        output2[node.split('_')[2]] = list[node];
        // variant 3
        // clone the node object into a new object
        var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list[node]));
        // add the id to the new object
        obj.id = node.split('_')[2];
        output3.push(obj);
    }
}
console.log(output1);
console.log(output2);
console.log(output3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = '{    "node_id_1": { "x": -87, "y": 149  },    "node_id_2": {        "x": -24,        "y": 50    },    "node_id_3": {       "x": 55,        "y": -32    } }'    ;
var jason = JSON.parse(text);


var jasonflatArr =new Array;
Object.keys(jason).forEach(function(key,index) {
    var jasonflat =new Object;
    jasonflat.id =key
    jasonflat.x =jason[key].x
    jasonflat.y =jason[key].y
    jasonflatArr.push(jasonflat)

});

document.write(jasonflatArr[0].id + " :" + "<br>"); // "node_id_1"
document.write(jasonflatArr[0].x + " :" + "<br>"); // -87
document.write(jasonflatArr[0].y + " :" + "<br>")  // 149
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var list = {
    "node_id_1": {
        "x": -87,
        "y": 149
    },
    "node_id_2": {
        "x": -24,
        "y": 50
    },
    "node_id_3": {
        "x": 55,
        "y": -32
    }
};

var getObjectByNodeId =  function(object, id) {
    return object["node_id_" + id];
  }

// get the object in the list that has node_id_2

var item = getObjectByNodeId(list,2);

document.write(JSON.stringify(item));
```

Comment: There is no `jQuery` tag on the question, so the assumption is that a plain JS answer should be supplied. Besides this is a completely wasteful usage of jQuery - you iterate over the object keys and try to find something that matches the key given... and if it matches RETURN IT and then lookup the item by the key. That you already know _by definition_ because you just constructed it and checked if it's present. You are trying to bend over backwards to do what `object["node_id_" + id]` already does and it never even needed any frameworks to do it.

Comment: Touche'. answer updated.